# In an SQL table, how to make sure, in each line, an attribute references another set of attributes from the same table?

Tags: sql, database, data-modeling

I am an SQL beginner trying to create a database for a tournament in a 1v1 game. I have a table like this, that records each game played:

```
CREATE TABLE Games(
  Player_1 VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  Player_2 VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  Winner VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  Primary KEY(Player_1, Player_2)
  )
```

How do I make sure each Winner is either the Player_1 or Player_2 from that same line?
Is Winner a foreign key?

Thank you

I tried this:

```
CREATE TABLE Games(
  Player_1 VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  Player_2 VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  Winner VARCHAR NOT NULL CHECK( (Winner in Player_1) OR (Winner IN Player_2) ),
  Primary KEY(Player_1, Player_2)
  )
```

But got an error message: subqueries prohibited in CHECK constraints

Comment: `Winner in (Player_1, Player_2)`. Or just have value 1 or 2 to give winner.

Comment: You have lots of syntax errors that I had to fix before I could verify the error.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: `VARCHAR` needs to be followed by a maximum length, e.g. `VARCHAR(100)`.

Comment: `IN` has to be followed by a subquery or a list in parentheses. `IN Player_1` is a syntax error.

Comment: Why not replace player_1  and player_2 with winner and loser and make them FKs to a player table?

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb: if you have column1 and column2 you should be using a [join table](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

```
create table games (
  -- or however your database does auto incrementing primary keys
  id bigint primary key auto_increment
);

create table players (
  id bigint primary key auto_increment,
  name varchar(255) not null
);

create table game_players (
  player_id bigint references players(id),
  game_id bigint references games(id),
  winner smallint default 0
);
```

Now the winner must be one of the players of the game, and you can easily track your players across games.

Use [triggers](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-triggers/) to ensure a game has only two players and only one winner.